# SQL Server - How to check if two items have the same relations to another set of items?

Tags: sql-server, relation

I have table with Employees (tblEmployee):

```
| ID | Name      |
| 1  | Smith     |
| 2  | Black     |
| 3  | Thompson  |
```

And a table with Roles (tblRoles):

```
| ID | Name      |
| 1  | Submitter |
| 2  | Receiver  |
| 3  | Analyzer  |
```

I have also a table with relations of Employees to their Roles with many to many relation type (tblEmployeeRoleRel):

```
| EmployeeID | RoleID  |
| 1          | 1       |
| 1          | 2       |
| 2          | 1       |
| 2          | 2       |
| 2          | 3       |
| 3          | 3       |
```

I need to select ID, Name from tblEmployee that have exaclty the same set of roles from tblEmployeeRoleRel as has the Employee with ID = 1. How can I do it?

Comment: Be more specific please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a where clause to limit the roles you're looking at to those of employeeID of 1 and use a having clause to make sure that the employee's role count matches that of employee1.

```
SELECT A.EmployeeID 
FROM tblEmployeeRoleRel A
WHERE Exists (SELECT 1 
              FROM tblEmployeeRoleRel B
              WHERE B.EmployeeID = 1
                and B.RoleID = A.RoleID)
GROUP BY A.EmployeeID
HAVING count(A.RoleID) = (SELECT count(C.RoleID) 
                          FROM tblEmployeeRoleRel C 
                          WHERE EmployeeID = 1)
```

This assumes that employeeID and roleID are unique in tblEmployeeRoleRel otherwise we may have to distinct the roleID fields above.

Comment: They are unique. This solution works for me, but it returns extra column with count, therefore I cannot use it as subquery, for example "...where EployeeID IN (...)"

Comment: you can remove count(A.RoleID) from the select, it was there to just show the total

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @EmployeeID int = 1 -- change this to whatever employee ID you like, or perhaps you'd pass an Employee ID to it in a stored procedure.
Select Distinct e.EmployeeID  -- normally distinct would incur extra overhead, but in this case you only want the employee IDs. not using Distinct when an employee has multiple roles will give you multiple employee IDs.
from tblEmployeeRoleRel as E 
where E.EmployeeID not in
(Select EmployeeID from tblEmployeeRoleRel where RoleID not in (Select RoleID from tblEmployeeRoleRel where Employee_ID = @EmployeeID)) 
and exists (Select EmployeeID from tblEmployeeRoleRel where EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID)  -- removes any "null" matches.
and E.Employee_ID <> @Employee_ID  -- this keeps the employee ID itself from matching.
```